# Order and make unique columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 columns which are `shop_id`, `shop_number` and `insert_date`. I want to get the list according to descending `insert_date`s by making unique `shop_id`, `shop_number`.

```
shop_id    shop_number     INSERT_DATE
4              8          2021-06-29 08:37:03
4              2          2021-06-27 16:37:03
4              8          2021-06-28 16:37:03
6              1          2021-06-29 16:37:03
7              9          2021-06-30 09:37:03
6              1          2021-06-30 11:37:03
7              9          2021-06-27 16:37:03
```

What I expect

```
shop_id    shop_number     INSERT_DATE
6              1          2021-06-30 11:37:03
7              9          2021-06-30 09:37:03
4              8          2021-06-29 08:37:03
4              2          2021-06-27 16:37:03
```

I tried the following but it doesn't yield expected result.

```
select shop_id, shop_number, INSERT_DATE
from mytablename with(NOLOCK) 
where shop_number is not null
group by shop_id, shop_number
order by INSERT_DATE desc
```

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY`, the query usually has aggregation functions.  In your case, I think you want `MAX()`:

```
select shop_id, shop_number, max(INSERT_DATE)
from mytablename 
where shop_number is not null
group by shop_id, shop_number
order by max(INSERT_DATE) desc;
```

Note:  Do not use the `WITH NOLOCK` hint unless you understand what it really does.  It means:  "Yes, you can fetch data that is not 100% accurate" and that is usually not desirable.

Comment: I didn't want to accept without comprehending the snippet, meaning I wanted to gain an ability that integrates same logic to other situations.

Answer (score 1):

`Row_Number` could be used to get rid of those type of duplicates.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY shop_id, shop_number ORDER BY INSERT_DATE DESC) as RN
   FROM mytablename 
)
SELECT shop_id,shop_number,INSERT_DATE
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```